# Function to find WiFi networks returns false

Tags: android, wifi

I am making program as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071981/limited-area-notification-serviece-using-wifi-ssid-for-sending-small-informatio)

And I made some code that should return found networks in main window

This is code that searches and returns WiFi networks (I found it online and just modified it a little bit)

I must mention that I am big newbie in Android, but I want to learn, and I stared to read Android for dummies, and I may have made something wrong in XML so i will put it here so you can see if there is any other mistake. I will send more updates if you need.

```
package com.vulisha.settosilent;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class WifiTester extends Activity {
    TextView mainText,outputText;
    WifiManager mainWifi;
    WifiReceiver receiverWifi;
    public List<ScanResult> wifiList;
    public StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    public List<String> wifiNetworks = new ArrayList<String>();


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);
       mainWifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
       receiverWifi = new WifiReceiver();
       registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
       mainWifi.startScan();
       mainText.setText("\\nStarting Scan...\\n");
       outputText.setText(sb);
       for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++)
        { wifiNetworks.add((wifiList.get(i)).toString()); }
        mainText.setText(sb);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Refresh");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item) {
        mainWifi.startScan();
        mainText.setText("Starting Scan");
        return super.onMenuItemSelected(featureId, item);
    }

    protected void onPause() {
        unregisterReceiver(receiverWifi);
        super.onPause();
    }

    protected void onResume() {
        registerReceiver(receiverWifi, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
        super.onResume();
    }

    class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            wifiList = mainWifi.getScanResults();
            for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){
                sb.append(new Integer(i+1).toString() + ".");
                sb.append((wifiList.get(i)).toString());
                sb.append("\\n");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

And here is main.XML//// EDIT: It is not main.xml it is fragment_main_dummy.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity$DummySectionFragment" >

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/section_label"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:text="@+id/TextView1"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="@+id/wifiList"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
              android:layout_below="@+id/section_label"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/section_label"
              android:id="@+id/textView"></TextView>
    <TextView android:text="@+id/wifiNetworks"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"

              android:id="@+id/wifiNetworks"
              android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
              android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
              android:layout_marginTop="13dp"></TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: which method returns false?

Comment: mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

in your `manifest.xml`

And of course make sure you are testing on a device on a network, with WiFi enabled.

Comment: I, am testing it on huawei ascend y300, I know that emulator doesn't have WiFI i will try It and report here

Comment: Ok now it is asking me user permissions, that is good , but still returnes false, do I maybe return wrong variable or something?

Comment: at line 27
`mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView1);`
in XML
`<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ></TextView>`

and if I am not mistaken it should return first this
`mainText.setText("\\nStarting Scan...\\n");` and then other changes

Comment: You realise that the scan happens very quickly right? Probably there is not enough time for you to even see the "Starting Scan" text.

Comment: Oh, I get it now, can you please tell me what part of the code should I save to another variable so I get array of found wireless networks?

Comment: `List<String> wifiNetworks = new ArrayList<String>();  for(int i = 0; i < wifiList.size(); i++){
wifiNetworks.add((wifiList.get(i)).toString());
            }`

Comment: Hy sorry for not responding earlier, here is new code(edited first post), and still giving false on all outputs :/

Answer (score 0):

The xml file you are giving to the `Activity` is not designed for that.
You need to provide a xml layout file with `RelativeLayout`,`LinearLayout` etc...
read http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html

Comment: Oh sorry i copy pasted from wrong, code is located in fragment_main_dummy.xml I will edit it now